# Vector spaces over exotic fields.

Tags: linear-algebra

Vector spaces can of course be defined over any arbitrary field. However with just one exception every vector space I've ever met "in the wild" are either real or complex. Does anybody know any other naturally occuring examples of non-real/complex vector spaces?

The exception I know of is if we take $S$ to be a set then the power set $P(S)$ together with disjoint union forms an abelian group. Then this can be considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by taking scalar multiplication in the only way possible. This is useful in proving certain facts about such groups.

Comment: Vector spaces over the rational numbers and over finite fields occur all over the place (indeed that's nearly the entire field of algebraic number theory). For that matter, any extension field is a vector space over the base field, and that vector space structure is important in determining the structure of the extension field.

Comment: Cohomology (for various theories) of varieties (or manifolds or topological spaces or sheaves on sites) produce another family of examples.

Comment: for an interesting algorithm working over $\mathbb F_p$ for well chosen $p$, see miniature 24: Perfect Matchings and Determinants in Matousek's *Thirty-three Miniatures*.  There is a pre-print here:  https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf

Comment: With "exotic fields" in the title I really thought this question was going to be about something like $\mathbb{F}_1$